# Using AirPrint printer on a public Wi-Fi

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, macbook-pro, printing

If I'm at a dorm and the only available Wi-Fi is through a public network such as a University's Wi-Fi, how can I prevent others from printing to my AirPrint enabled printer?

I would like to be able to print from a MacBook and iPhone wirelessly, but would like to prevent others from doing so. Ideally, I wouldn't want this printer to even show up for anyone except for me.

Comment: You do not need to enable the sharing.

Comment: What make and model is your AirPrint enabled printer?